# Do not allow concurrent runs Azure devops

Tags: python, unix, azure-devops

I a pre merge PR validation pipeline A which has 4 stages for deploying into a salesforce org:

1. Git checkout
2. ANT Deploy package 1
3. ANT Deploy package 2

Since this pipeline is queued on every PR raise event, we have reached a situation wherein the deployment threads are conflicting with each other and failing due to dependencies (Salesforce org can run only 1 thread at a time unfortunately.).

I want to ensure that the next run does not start until the first one has finished. It remains in the queue, but it does not start.

E.g.: 2 PR's raises results in 2 runs(Run #1 and Run#2). Although Run#2 is queued, but I do not want it to start the execution until Run#1 is completed(Build result status does not matter here as they will be from different status branches).

In Jenkins do not allow concurrent builds was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Devops, I am afraid that there is no such setting to not allow concurrent builds in Multi-stage Pipeline.

I can reproduce your situation. When two pipeline runs are triggered, stages will run alternately. There is no option to control their order for the time being.

**Workaround:**

You could add the **Approvals type** environment to the build definition.

Here are the steps:

Step1: Create a environment in **Pipelines-> Envrionments**

Step2: Add the Approvals to the environment.

[image]

Step3: Change the Yaml definition.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  
stages:
- stage: QA
  jobs:
  - deployment: test
    displayName: deploy Web App
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-latest'
    environment: 'test'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo Hello world


- stage: QB
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
     - script: echo "B"

- stage: QC
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
     - script: echo "B"
    
- stage: QD
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
     - script: echo "B"
```

**Note:** if you need to add the environment to yaml, the job is deployment type.

Then when the Two PRs triggers the pipeline, the two runs need to be approved. In this case, you can manually control their run order.

On the other hand, this requirement is valuable.

You could add your request for this feature on [our UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.